# Purchased App in W10 Store remains in trial expired mode

Tags: windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

Some customers are reporting that our App in W10 Store remains in trial expired mode even after purchase. THE  warning dialog is given by store itself, we do not have any STORE API implemented in our legacy app.

How to fix?  Nowadays store limits itself the trial period, there is no code needed to app for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix? Nowadays store limits itself the trial period, there is no code needed to app for that.

If your app is a desktop application, you need to configure the `StoreContext`object to specify the owner window for modal dialogs, or this object will return inaccurate data or errors.

Have you made this configuration? For more details, you could refer to [Using the StoreContext class with the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#using-the-storecontext-class-with-the-desktop-bridge).

Comment: Using StoreContext is optional.

Comment: Please note that `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace is not supported in Windows desktop applications that use the Desktop Bridge or in apps or games that use a development sandbox in Dev Center . Check 
[Choose which namespace to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#choose-which-namespace-to-use).

Comment: I am not using any namespace,  there is no requirement to use these, store shold be able to make transactions without coding ecommerce integration  to app.